# Does anyone know how to delete a 3D Model of a part in AUTOTRAX DEX?

Tags: pcb, cad, 3d

Trying to delete a 3d part but not sure how to.
Using AutoTrax Design Express Version: 2023.3.1

Comment: S_D - Hi, Although the last meta discussions I can find indicated a general view that PCB CAD software questions were on-topic (i.e. allowed) here, [this answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7033) makes some relevant points. If that software is relatively uncommon, you are less likely to find people here who can help than with other more common EDA packages. I found a (quiet) user forum, but the support URL linked in this [forum topic](https://forum.dexpcb.com/viewtopic.php?t=20) doesn't resolve for me. You may be better trying to contact the company or other users. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your advice Sam!